# Pie Chart Slice without white border in c3 js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am using C3 js for plottin Pie Chart. I am able to plot it successfully. I am trying to customize the Pie with respect to the slice. I need to plot the Pie chart without the White border for all the slices. I am not sure how to do this in c3 js. It would be of great help if anyone can let me know how to plot pie chart without the white border.

Thanks and Regards,
Saravanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change color using this css i have changed to gray color you can change as per your requirement

```
.c3-chart-arc path {
    stroke: #666;
}
```

Comment: Any way to do this via the `generate()` parameters/object?